# Google Script Calendar Event List Search in Multi-languages Environment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Using Google script Calendar.events.list in a multi-language environment.

I am not sure if a decoding function is necessary.

```
function findEvents(user, keyword, start, end, optSince) {
  var params = {
    q: keyword,
    timeMin: formatDateAsRFC3339(start),
    timeMax: formatDateAsRFC3339(end),
    showDeleted: true,
  };
  if (optSince) {
    // This prevents the script from examining events that have not been
    // modified since the specified date (that is, the last time the
    // script was run).
    params.updatedMin = formatDateAsRFC3339(optSince);
  }
  var pageToken = null;
  var events = [];
  do {
    params.pageToken = pageToken;
    var response;
    try {
      response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error retriving events for %s, %s: %s; skipping',
          user, keyword, e.toString());
      continue;
    }
    events = events.concat(response.items.filter(function(item) {
      return shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, item);
    }));
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return events;
}
```

The keyword can be 'out of office', 'offline', 'vacation', 'ooo', and '不在' as our calendar event can be in English or Japanese. The english keyword works, but not the Japanese.

Comment: Cross https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-script-community/7vC9vF_FlV0

Comment: Hi there @Tim! You could try to feed the search terms as an array, have you tested that? Additionally you could execute several API requests. Would these approaches be valid for your scenario?